# Does MongoDb have functions where you can specify the collection it queries as a parameter to the function?

Tags: mongodb, function, collections, parameters

In MSSQL this can't be done (one can do it with a Stored Proc but not with a table valued function).  Can this be done in Mongodb?

I'm using the C# MongoDb drivers, but the question is more about whether you can construct a MongoDb function even in javascript through a client like Studio T3.

Comment: Can you please provide more details about what you want to achieve ? It depends on the connector to the mongo you use, but i'd say yes you can.

Comment: Do you mean [getCollection()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/)?